# Escoger la hora en TextBox ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

¿Es posible que en un `TextBox` seleccione solo la hora? Ya que yo quiero escoger la hora y que me salga ejemplo

> 17:36:34

Como la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pierro, recuerda que ASP es muy diferente de ASP.NET. Esto puede llevar a que la pregunta sea confusa y que te den respuestas a tecnologías que no estás usando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno para realizar tenemos que agregar un Plugin que se llama ClockPicker lo podran encontrar para descargar :

https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/

Muy aparte tenemos que agregar tanto JS/JQUERY/CSS:

```
 <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/css/github.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="dist/bootstrap-clockpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/highlight.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/jquery-clockpicker.min.js"></script>


<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-2">


        <div class="input-group clockpicker" data-placement="bottom" data-alignment="left" data-donetext="Done">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" value="18:00"/>
            <span class="input-group-addon">

                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
            </div>

    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.clockpicker').clockpicker();
        </script>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

En ese caso va a depender de la implementación del navegador.

Prueba usando [este plugin](http://timepicker.co/) de JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.timepicker').timepicker({});
});
```

Comment: ¿Nos podrías dar un poco más de detalle de qué es y a qué te refieres con *la implementación del navegador*?